# Problems intsalling Eclipse 2019-12

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-installer, eclipse-2019-12

I wanted to Install Eclipse 2019-12 however do I get an error once I want to open the installer.
It says:

```
Internal error:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

When I click on `details` it says:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil$ReflectionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.URISchemeUtil.<clinit>(URISchemeUtil.java:44)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.urischeme.internal.registration.RegistryWriter.<init>(RegistryWriter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.urischeme.internal.registration.RegistrationWindows.<init>(RegistrationWindows.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.urischeme.IOperatingSystemRegistration.getInstance(IOperatingSystemRegistration.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to make private static byte[] java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.stringToByteArray(java.lang.String) accessible: module java.prefs does not "opens java.util.prefs" to unnamed module @726a17c4
    at org.eclipse.urischeme.internal.registration.WinRegistry.<clinit>(WinRegistry.java:68)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private static byte[] java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.stringToByteArray(java.lang.String) accessible: module java.prefs does not "opens java.util.prefs" to unnamed module @726a17c4
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.urischeme.internal.registration.WinRegistry.<clinit>(WinRegistry.java:66)
    ... 25 more
```

When I click on `update` it says:

```
This is an emergency update. Continue?

To lower the risks of problems duringthis update it will be implied thta you accept new licenses or unsigned content.
```

I have installed Java JDK 15.0.2 just before.

How can I make this Eclipse Installation work?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Eclipse 2019-12 is 5 releases behind and was released before Java 15. Use the current Eclipse 2021-03 that comes with Java 15 embedded instead.

Comment: That version of Eclipse is using code that does not work in Java 15 but did work in earlier versions of Java. The current Eclipse uses different code that will work.